# Extract only part of a text just before delimiter '/'?

Tags: bash, shell, file, mime

I need to find all the mime-type of all the files in the folder.I wrote a small snippet like this.

```
 for i in $(find /home/someFolder -type f);do file -b $i --mime-type;done
```

This is returning the following output.

```
text/html
application/msword
application/msword
text/html
text/html
text/html
application/msword
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

But can i get the extracted information from these output like only `html` or `msword` or `png`.

```
html
msword
msword
```

Are there any libraries which I can use to know the detailed information of the file which should include mime type,size,strings inside the file and any other behavioural information.Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0L1 file -b --mime-type | cut -d/ -f2
```

Much faster and safer than your `for` approach.
(Obviously, replace `.` with the path you want to start your search from.)

Comment: Since the file names are not kept during that process, maybe adding a last pipe stage with `sort -u` to avoid duplicates would make sense?

Comment: Yes, `sort -u` would make sense. You can even `sort | uniq -c` to get counts of the various types...